# Best way to import a large html template to wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying import my current site built with HTML,CSS and Javascript into a custom Wordpress theme but I have one problem;the Javascript files are too big,making loading of some elements impossible.
Please reach out with any working suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

I have tried everything